# Hyperref package problem

Tags: hyperref, bibentry

I am compiling my CV. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, bibentry, longtable}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{\bfseries\Huge My name}
\author{\large{\textbf{\textit{February 2019}}}}
\date{}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.85\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{filecontents}{my2.bib}
@book{bnm,
title={Title},
author={Author, 1 and Author, 2},
publisher={Cambridge University Press},
address={Cambridge}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{20pt}
\section*{Personal Information}
Date of Birth: XXXX\\[7pt]
Citizenship: XXXX\\[7pt]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Address:
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Mine in my city,\\
    in my place
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\\[7pt]
Phone: +39 123 45678\\[7pt]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Email:
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\medskip \smallskip
    email1@email.com\\ 
    email2@email.com
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\\[7pt]
Personal website: www.mysite.com

\section*{Education}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&{Ph.D. in Economics}\\
&Supervisor: My friend \\
& Thesis: My title\\
& Thesis committee: ABC; DEF\\[5pt]
\end{longtable}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{my2}
\section*{Research}
\subsection*{\it Main publications}
\subsection*{\it Books}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2014&\bibentry{bnm}\\
\end{longtable}

\section*{References}
Upon request.


\end{document}
```

Everything works fine. I would like to make the address of my website and my emails clickable. Hence I load the package `hyperref`. However when I do so, I got the following error message when compiling:

```
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \bibitem{bnm}
```

Apparently, there is a conflict between the list of references and the additional package `hyperref`.

Is there any way I can overcome this? Maybe, another package? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

These are the first lines of the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840)
entering extended mode
```

I use TeXworks v. 0.6.2 (MikTex 2.9.6840)

**Second update**

I updated my release, but still the problem persists. This is the first line of the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
entering extended mode
```

**Third update**

I updated MikTeX as user as well, but still the problem persists.

This is the complete logfile (after using `\listfiles`)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/Dario/Desktop/Nuova cartella/prova2.tex"
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/natbib\bibentry.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\longtable.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\switch.def")
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def"))))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))

LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./my2.bib'.


No file prova2.aux.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
Overfull \hbox (20.06664pt too wide) in alignment at lines 56--61
 [] [] 
No file prova2.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `bnm' undefined on input line 69.


Overfull \hbox (20.06664pt too wide) in alignment at lines 68--70
 [] [] 
[1{C:/Users/Dario/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]
(prova2.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   array.sty    2018/12/30 v2.4k Tabular extension package (FMi)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
bibentry.sty    2007/10/30 1.5 (PWD)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)+ FMi change
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
   babel.sty    2018/11/13 3.27 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
 english.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
hyperref.sty    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
 ***********


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `prova2.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiK
TeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbxti10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2
.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb>
Output written on prova2.pdf (2 pages, 52366 bytes).
SyncTeX written on prova2.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on prova2.log.
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
The top-level auxiliary file: prova2.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: my2.bib
Warning--empty year in bnm
(There was 1 warning)
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/Dario/Desktop/Nuova cartella/prova2.tex"
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/natbib\bibentry.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\longtable.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\switch.def")
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def"))))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))

LaTeX Warning: File `my2.bib' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.

(prova2.aux) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base\supp-pdf.mkii
"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
(prova2.out) (prova2.out)
Overfull \hbox (20.06664pt too wide) in alignment at lines 56--61
 [] [] 
(prova2.bbl

! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \bibitem{bnm}

?
```

Note that the name of my tex file is `prova2.tex`.

Comment: Since you are using MikTeX? Did you update as both user and admin. Might be an idea to post the entire log, then we can easily see when a file is taken from the user part and the admin part of the miktex installation. It might also be an idea to add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, this prints a list of used packages at the end of the log file.

Comment: @daleif actually I updated miktex as admin not as user. I thought it could be the same. I will update as user as well and see what happens and in case I will post the log file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you missed to call package `natbib` (please note that `bibentry` is a part of `natbib`).  Therefore you have to change the bib style from `plain` to `plainnat`.

Package `hyperref` should be called in your case last.

So please see the following code (code changings are marked with `<=====`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bnm,
  title     = {Title},
  author    = {Author, One and Author, Two},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  address   = {Cambridge},
  year      = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{array, xcolor, longtable}

\usepackage{natbib} % <=================================================
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <===================================[colorlinks]


\title{\bfseries\Huge My name}
\author{\large{\textbf{\textit{February 2019}}}}
\date{}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.84\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{20pt}
\section*{Personal Information}
Date of Birth: XXXX\\[7pt]
Citizenship: XXXX\\[7pt]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Address:
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Mine in my city,\\
    in my place
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\\[7pt]
Phone: +39 123 45678\\[7pt]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Email:
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\medskip \smallskip
    \href{mailto:email1@email.com}{email1@email.com}\\ % <==============
    \href{mailto:email2@email.com}{email2@email.com} % <================
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\\[7pt]
Personal website: \url{www.mysite.com} % <==============================

\section*{Education}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&{Ph.D. in Economics}\\
&Supervisor: My friend \\
& Thesis: My title\\
& Thesis committee: ABC; DEF\\[5pt]
\end{longtable}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % plain
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\section*{Research}
\subsection*{\it Main publications}
\subsection*{\it Books}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2014&\bibentry{bnm}\\
\end{longtable}

\section*{References}
Upon request.

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Make sure you remove all temp files before compiling again

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, bibentry, longtable}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%%
\usepackage[
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
  ]{hyperref}
%%

\title{\bfseries\Huge My name}
\author{\large{\textbf{\textit{February 2019}}}}
\date{}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.85\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{filecontents}{my2.bib}
@book{bnm,
title={Title},
author={Author, 1 and Author, 2},
publisher={Cambridge University Press},
address={Cambridge}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{20pt}
\section*{Personal Information}
Date of Birth: XXXX\\[7pt]
Citizenship: XXXX\\[7pt]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Address:
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Mine in my city,\\
    in my place
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\\[7pt]
Phone: +39 123 45678\\[7pt]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Email:
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\medskip \smallskip
    \href{mailto:email1@email.com}{email1@email.com}\\
    \href{mailto:email2@email.com}{email2@email.com}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\\[7pt]
Personal website: \href{www.mysite.com}{www.mysite.com}

\section*{Education}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&{Ph.D. in Economics}\\
&Supervisor: My friend \\
& Thesis: My title\\
& Thesis committee: ABC; DEF\\[5pt]
\end{longtable}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{my2}
\section*{Research}
\subsection*{\it Main publications}
\subsection*{\it Books}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2014&\bibentry{bnm}\\
\end{longtable}

\section*{References}
Upon request.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: actually I did. I removed every temporary file. I also put the file in another empty folder. Might it be something related to updating the package?